# Assign a numerical value when text is entered into a cell

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a Column of employee names A6-A15: John Doe
and a row of time cells B5-N5: 7:00AM to 7:00PM.

I would like it so that whenever I input any text into a cell in any time row that it is assigned a 1 value for that hour. So that at the end of every row is a total of that employees hours for the day.

Not sure if this possible. I am very new to excel. I know how to do basic math formulas in cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an IF formula (multiple) would be my go to for doing exactly what you want to do (someone might come in with a shorter version). This is a formula tailored to exactly the Sheet contents as you have described above. I would create a TOTAL in cell 05 and then under it for each person you'll need to increment it by 1.

So, here is the formula for the first person:

```
=IF($B6="",0,1)+IF($C6="",0,1)+IF($D6="",0,1)+IF($E6="",0,1)+IF($F6="",0,1)+IF($G6="",0,1)+IF($H6="",0,1)+IF($I6="",0,1)+IF($J6="",0,1)+IF($K6="",0,1)+IF($L6="",0,1)+IF($M6="",0,1)+IF($N6="",0,1)
```

To explain the formula, I'll start at the beginning. 

The IF formula will check a CELL EX: $B6 by = "" <-Nothing. 

Then, if that is correct it will enter in 0.

If it is not correct it will enter in 1.

So, =IF(CELL=VALUE, Return if true, Return if false). The + Adds each IF statement together which gives you a running total of the hours added up. Again you'll need to increment the CELL number by 1 for each row you go down.

This can be put into a sheet for each day, so one sheet for MONDAY, one for TUESDAY, so on (that way you can just copy and paste the formula for each total without having to worry about incrementing values).

Please comment below if I can explain anything further for you!

Comment: Thank you this was perfect, and exactly what I was looking for. Now, I do have another question. Say I have numerous employees and under each hour I have the task they were working on such as Drywall. Is there a way I can tally every time a particular task was performed? So that I have a total number of times a task was done at the end of the week from all employees. Kind of like a  word count.

Comment: @Richard yes, you can. Currently, I'm on mobile, but when I get to my desktop I will whip this up. :)